# Checking for changed fields - Identifying an empty array & Field Type

Tags: 7

This is probably a simple question, but I am not finding it right away. I have a mostly working function to check for changed fields in a form. Here is the snippet checking for change:

```
// Check the number of values for each field, or if they are populated at all.
$old_field_count = (isset($old_field[LANGUAGE_NONE]) ? count($old_field[LANGUAGE_NONE]) : 0);
$new_field_count = (isset($new_field[LANGUAGE_NONE]) ? count($new_field[LANGUAGE_NONE]) : 0);
```

The problem I am a having is when I submit the form, empty text fields always respond as changed. The $old_field_count is not set, so comes up as 0. The $new_field_count is 1, because for some reason it is an empty array.

```
old count 0
new count 1 ... (Array, 1 element)
    0 (Array, 1 element)
        value (String, 0 characters )
```

There has to be an easy way to say "If ($new_field_count = "An empty Array") {$new_field_count = 0;}"

Edit: I found my answer in part. I tried `If (empty($new_field_count[0])) {$new_field_count = 0;}` but that just breaks any empty field that isn't a text field. So now I am thinking I have to additionally identify if it is a text field.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to identify if it's a text field because not all form elements will store the values under the same keys (e.g. textfield vs file upload field vs entity reference). This will have to be more complex. For testing, install Devel module and use the `dpm()` function - it will show you a tree of submitted values and their identifiers. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I've got it!

```
// Check the number of values for each field, or if they are populated at all.
$old_field_count = (isset($old_field[LANGUAGE_NONE]) ? count($old_field[LANGUAGE_NONE]) : 0);
$new_field_count = (isset($new_field[LANGUAGE_NONE]) ? count($new_field[LANGUAGE_NONE]) : 0);

If (empty($new_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] && ($field_info[type] == 'text' || $field_info[type] == 'text_long')) {
    $new_field_count = 0;
}

if ($old_field_count != $new_field_count) {
  // The two versions have a different number of values. Something has changed.
  $fields_changed[] = $field_name;
}
```